# expo: No credentials configured for app with bundle identifier

Tags: ios, react-native, build, expo

ios build on expo cli is failing with the following error

```
PS C:\Users\Sarath.N15\IdeaProjects\face-app> expo build:ios
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ │
│ There is a new version of expo-cli available (4.1.6). │
│ You are currently using expo-cli 4.1.3 │
│ Install expo-cli globally using the package manager of your choice; │
│ for example: npm install -g expo-cli to get the latest version │
│ │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
√ Choose the build type you would like: » archive

Checking if there is a build in progress…

Accessing credentials for sarath_n15 in project FaceApp
√ Do you have access to the Apple account that will be used for submitting this app to the App Store? … yes

› Log in to your Apple Developer account to continue
√ Apple ID: … sarath.n15@*******************
› Restoring session C:\Users\Sarath.N15.app-store\auth\sarath.n15@\cookie
› Team ***************************************
› Provider ****************************************
√ Logged in Local session
√ Bundle identifier registered com.my.build.id
× Failed to sync capabilities com.my.build.id
Failed to prepare all credentials.
The next time you build, we will automatically use the following configuration:
No credentials configured for app @sarath_n15/AppName with bundle identifier com.my.build.id

This request is forbidden for security reasons - You are not allowed to perform this operation. Please check with one of your Team Admins, or, if you need further assistance, please contact Apple Developer Program Support. https://developer.apple.com/support
UnexpectedAppleResponse: This request is forbidden for security reasons - You are not allowed to perform this operation. Please check with one of your Team Admins, or, if you need further assistance, please contact Apple Developer Program Support. https://developer.apple.com/support
at ProvisioningClientAPI.parseResponse (C:\Users\Sarath.N15\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\apple-utils\build\index.js:1:1095543)
at ProvisioningClientAPI.requestAndParseAsync (C:\Users\Sarath.N15\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\apple-utils\build\index.js:1:1094204)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
at ProvisioningClientAPI.fetchSingleModelAsync (C:\Users\Sarath.N15\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\apple-utils\build\index.js:1:1093919)
at ProvisioningClientAPI.patchModelAsync (C:\Users\Sarath.N15\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\apple-utils\build\index.js:1:1094033)
at BundleId.updateBundleIdCapabilityAsync (C:\Users\Sarath.N15\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\apple-utils\build\index.js:1:1104952)
at ensureBundleIdExistsWithNameAsync (C:\Users\Sarath.N15\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\appleApi\ensureAppExists.ts:79:7)
at IOSBuilder.produceCredentials (C:\Users\Sarath.N15\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\build\ios\IOSBuilder.ts:240:7)
at IOSBuilder.prepareCredentials (C:\Users\Sarath.N15\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\build\ios\IOSBuilder.ts:155:7)
at IOSBuilder.run (C:\Users\Sarath.N15\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\build\ios\IOSBuilder.ts:62:7)
```

I’m using a company account where they’ve added me as a developer.

Any idea what's causing it or how to solve this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: @mylescc please see my answer below, hope its helpful for you

Answer (score 2):

I was using a developer account added under an organisation account. My account didn't have the required permissions that expo requires to automatically do the magic. So what I did is: selected 'no' when it asks, Do you have access to the Apple account?? Then expo asked me to provide the location of my certificate files in my local.

I had to contact the org account manager for some of the certificates. Some, I was able to create and download from developer center.